# Call onReportLocation through reflection

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call onReportLocation() method: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-c2f2-release/location/java/com/android/internal/location/ILocationProviderManager.aidl#38

```
Class<?> ILocationProviderManager = Class.forName("com.android.internal.location.ILocationProviderManager");
Object ilpm = ILocationProviderManager.newInstance();
Method method = ilpm.getClass().getMethod("onReportLocation", Location.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ilpm, location);
```

I tried using this code to call it from reflection but I get:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.android.internal.location.ILocationProviderManager> cannot be instantiated
```

If I use Method method = ILocationProviderManager.getMethod("onReportLocation", Location.class); instead, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.android.internal.location.ILocationProviderManager, but got java.lang.Class<com.android.internal.location.ILocationProviderManager>
```

I'm pretty new with Java Reflection, can you please tell me what did I do wrong? Or is there another way to call onReportLocation? Thanks

Comment: Please note the `@UnsupportedAppUsage` annotation on that method. And, you might want to read [this](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for the link, that method is greylisted (says in debug), which is ok with me for now: Non-SDK interfaces that are currently unrestricted and your app can use. Note however, that these interfaces are unsupported and subject to change without notice.

I'll just have to keep track with any changes.